# Etimología de chichón

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

Por lo visto la palabra [chichón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8jThnmU) aparece desde el diccionario de autoridades, sin embargo, no se muestra origen alguno de la palabra en las versiones del DLE. En [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chicho.n) dan como origen el *abscessionnes* latino, pero como única versión, no me termina de convencer.

¿Alguien puede confirmar esa versión o presentar otra más convincente con las fuentes concernientes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te indico la etimología que da Corominas en su diccionario etimológico abreviado:

> **CHICHÓN** 'bulto que de resultas de un golpe se hace en el cuero de la cabeza', 1601. Voz común al castellano y al it. *ciccione*; de origen incierto, probablemente deriv. del vocablo infantil *chicha* 'carne', de creación expresiva.

Hay en el CORDE casos incluso anteriores al año 1601 que propone Corominas:

> *Y assí, es tan negro, de usado, un parche de terciopelo negro en el rostro, un chichón en una sien, una señal con falta de güeso en la frente, que casi no se echa de ver en ello.*
>
> Juan de Cárdenas, "Primera parte de los problemas y secretos maravillosos de las Indias", 1591 (México).

E incluso uno anterior:

> *De un cardenal legado, que era gordillo, estando en la corte del emperador Carlos Quinto, dijo don Diego de Mendoza, conde de Mélito, que más parecía chichón que cardenal.*
>
> Melchor de Santa Cruz de Dueñas, "Floresta española", 1574 (España).

Curiosamente, si la frase anterior es cierta y el citado Diego de Mendoza se refiere a [Diego Hurtado de Mendoza y Lemos, I conde de Mélito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Hurtado_de_Mendoza_y_Lemos), este falleció en 1536 por lo que la palabra *chichón* debió ser usada antes de ese año. Aunque también pudo ser [Diego Hurtado de Mendoza y de la Cerda, II conde de Mélito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Hurtado_de_Mendoza_y_de_la_Cerda), fallecido en 1578 y entonces el texto citado sería más reciente y fiable. Ambos pudieron estar en la corte de Carlos V.

Por cierto, Covarrubias (1611) coincide con Corominas:

> CHICHON, el tolondron, o torondron, de thorus: en Valenciano torondo, que se levanta en la frente, o en otra parte de la cabeça, causado de algun golpe, que aporreò y no sacò sangre, pero esta se ayuntò en aquella parte, y levantò el pellejo pegado al huesso de la cabeça, que no tiene casi carne, y porque levanta alli aquel vulto carnoso se llamò chichon, de chicha, que vale carne.

Es decir, que decir *chichón* es como decir que tienes un trozo de carne grande donde no debería haberlo.

La primera aparición de la palabra en diccionarios es en el español-inglés de Percival en 1591:

> Chichon, a bliſter, a pinſwell, *Pustula.*

Por último, el diccionario de Rosal, también de 1611, propone:

> Chichon, levantamiento de la Carne causado de algun golpe, de citione Lat. que del verbo Cire quiere decir lo mismo.

Según [una respuesta](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/9006/2646) en el sitio de latín, se podría referir al verbo *[cĭĕo, cīvi, cĭtum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DC%3Aentry%20group%3D42%3Aentry%3Dcieo)*, derivado de *cĭo, cīre*, con el sentido de "poner en movimiento" y de ahí "mover" o "agitar". La forma *citio* sería el sustantivo regular derivado del verbo que podría haber significado "golpe". Nota curiosa: de *cĭo* se deriva [*accĭo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=accio&toc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DA%3Aentry%20group%3D12), con el significado de "llamar", "invocar" o incluso "ir a buscar", que los fans de Harry Potter conocen muy bien.